# Porque o meu canvas não está funcionando corretamente?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

No código acima eu possuo um `<canvas>` de 500px x 500px e nele um quadrado de 50px x 50px, mas o que acontece é que o quadrado está maior do que deveria e está distorcido porque isso está acontecendo e como corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema acontece porque, conforme [especificações](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#attr-canvas-width) do `<canvas>`:

> O elemento canvas tem dois atributos para controlar o tamanho do
>   bitmap do elemento: `width` e `height`. Esses atributos, quando
>   especificados, devem ter valores que são números inteiros não
>   negativos válidos. As regras para analisar números inteiros não
>   negativos devem ser usadas para obter seus valores numéricos. Se um
>   atributo estiver ausente ou se a análise de seu valor retornar um
>   erro, o valor padrão deverá ser usado. O atributo `width` é padronizado
>   em **300** e o atributo `height` é padronizado em **150**.

No seu caso, é como se estivesse pegando o canvas `300x150` e esticando para ficar `500x500`. Você pode ver isso "na prática" clicando no botão do exemplo abaixo (**Mudar CSS**).

Para o seu código funcionar corretamente, bastaria especificar os atributos `height` e `width` no HTML ou via JS (**Mudar atributos**).

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

function mudarCss() {
  canvas.style.height = "500px";
  canvas.style.width = "500px";
}

function mudarAtributos() {
  canvas.style.height = "";
  canvas.style.width = "";
  canvas.setAttribute('height', '100');
  canvas.setAttribute('width', '200');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onClick="mudarCss()">Mudar CSS</button>
    <button onClick="mudarAtributos()">Mudar atributos</button>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
```

Note que se você modificar isso via **JavaScript**, é necessário "redesenhar" o que estava no `<canvas>`. O Motivo pode ser encontrado nas próprias especificações, estou adaptando abaixo:

> Sempre que os atributos de conteúdo de largura e altura são definidos,
>   removidos, alterados ou redundantemente com o valor que eles já
>   possuem, o agente do usuário deve executar a ação correspondente:
>
> **2d** Siga as etapas para [definir as dimensões do bitmap](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions) com os valores numéricos dos atributos de conteúdo de largura e altura.

E o passo 1 dessas etapas de definição das dimensões do bitmap é:

> [Redefina](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#reset-the-rendering-context-to-its-default-state) o contexto de renderização para seu estado padrão.

E essa redefinição, por definição significa:

> Quando o agente do usuário deve redefinir o contexto de renderização para seu estado padrão, deve limpar a pilha de estados de desenho e tudo o que esse estado de desenho consiste nos valores iniciais.

Comment: Mas como eu faria para deixar na largura e altura especificada na pergunta, sem ser o padrão?

Comment: Conforme eu disse, via HTML (especificando os atributos `width` e `height`) ou JavaScript (função `mudarAtributos()`). Exemplo de html: `<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">`

Comment: Mas não está funcionando com os tamanhos citados.

Comment: Modifiquei o Snippet. Se você executar, ele começará 500x500 corretamente, qual o problema no seu caso? Você removeu o CSS que modifica a altura e largura?

Comment: Agora funcionou muito, obrigada! :)

Comment: Só uma outra dúvida porque o `fillStyle` deve vir antes do `fillRect()`?

Comment: O método `fillRect()` desenha o seu "objeto". Então o que acontece é que você está indicando a cor **antes** de desenhar, se tentar indicar depois ele já terá desenhado e então a cor não será aplicada

Comment: Verdade! faz sentido kk mas muito obrigada de novo.